# How do I export FFmpeg frames from H265 4K video in lossless best quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to FFmpeg and I'm trying to extract frames from a 4K HEVC/H265 MKV video, but they are extracted the file size is unusually too little for a 4K image extraction. Tried both JPEG and PNG, the best was JPEG. 
I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i videoname.mkv -q:v 2 output_%03.jpeg
```

I heard that `qscale:v` does the trick, but the output picture quality is worse than the "film" one.

Is there a command that I'm missing?

Comment: *"the best was JPEG"*. What was better about JPEG compared to PNG? *"output picture quality is worse than the 'film' one"* How are you comparing? Modern video encoders use techniques to save bits in ways that are not as noticeable in a moving picture. Looking at a static screenshot is not really a fair comparison to how a video is perceived by the viewer.

Comment: loses would be `fmpeg -i videoname.mkv out.y4m`